# Integral over power spectral density

Tags: power-spectral-density, statistics, random-process, integration

The Wikipedia entry on [Spectral Density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density) (PSD) has one confusing line:

> Summation or integration of the spectral components yields the total power (for a physical process) or variance (in a statistical process)

But would the total power correspond to the uncentralized second moment, so variance + mean<sup>2</sup>? In particular, there are stationary processes with a nonzero mean. Is the integral over the PSD still *just* the variance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Summation or integration of the spectral components yields the total power (for a physical process)

yes, that's how "power density" is defined ...

> or variance (in a statistical process)

For any bound density, that's true.

> But would the total power correspond to the uncentralized second moment, so variance + mean²?

Yes, but if you have a process with a non-zero mean, that would imply that the spectral power density at $f=0$ diverges (a "Dirac delta $\delta(f)$" with "infinite height"), and that would imply the PSD isn't actually a function (it's still a distribution / test function, but seriously, this is just getting into math).

If you will, just imagine your "mean" is something at *very low frequencies* ($f\in[-\epsilon;\epsilon]$), but not concentrated to *exactly* $f=0$.

Still works out the same, for anything technical (because nothing will ever experience whatever process they're observing for eternity, so who's to say whether something happens at $0\,\text{Hz}$ or $10^{-24}\,\text{Hz}$?).

Honestly, the wording of the article isn't the greatest.